# What are some Eclipse project files I should not include in my project repos?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am developing an android application in eclipse and using git as the version control system. When I first created the git repo, I accidentally added some eclipse project files. As a result, when I clone the project to a different environment, (e.g. another window/linux computer) there are some project properties/directories that are based on my initial environment and can cause issues in the new environment (directory doesn't exist, toolchain doesn't exist, etc).

What are some eclipse project files I should exclude from the repo to ensure that the project can be build in any environment assuming they have already set up eclipse to work with android apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

bin/gen folders and local.properties files should be ignored. That's should be all you need to ignore

Comment: what about .cproject or .project?

Comment: .project should be committed. .cproject also seems like it should be committed also based on what I'm reading about it. Although, I've never actually had one generated by eclipse in the 100s of projects I've created/imported/worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Files in the `/gen` and `/bin` folders, because these contain files generated during compilation and/or building. If you are using proguard, files in `/proguard` should also be excluded, though you should keep them somewhere so that you can remap the class names when you get stack traces from crash reports on Google Play.

Comment: I know about the two folders. I was more asking about specific eclipse project files like .cproject or .project.

Comment: None that I can think of other than local.properties, as dymmeh mentioned. None of my Eclipse projects contain any `.project` or `.cproject` files.

Comment: But something must be storing settings like what toolchains your project should use. And on windows I might have it set to Cygwin GCC but I want to make sure if someone is on Linux, then it should be set to Linux GCC. But as it is now, it's automatically set to Cygwin GCC which must be a setting saved somewhere?